# Can't build, qmake.exe crashes in Qt Creator

Tags: c++, qt, mingw, qmake

I'm using Qt Creator on Windows XP SP3. I want to develop C++ desktop applications.

I made a new project. Everytime I click build, it appears a window which says:

> qmake.exe has encountered a problem and needs to close. We are sorry for the inconvenience.

In Qt Creator, something similar to this appears:

```
20:36:55: Running build steps for project yyy...
20:36:55: Starting: "d:\qtsdk\desktop\qt\4.8.1\mingw\bin\qmake.exe" D:\...\yyy.pro -r -spec win32-g++ "CONFIG+=declarative_debug"
20:38:00: The process "d:\qtsdk\desktop\qt\4.8.1\mingw\bin\qmake.exe" crashed.
Error while building project yyy (target: Desktop)
When executing build step 'qmake'
```

I can't build, I have reinstalled the software but it keeps giving the same error.

Can you give me any idea of what is happening?

Comment: from start->qt sdk->desktop -> qt for desktop(mingw) run in console mode, then execute qmake -v , see what happened

Comment: I am using Qt Creator, I selected to install Qt Desktop and Qt Creator. I want to create GUIs. I did the console thing and I got: Setting up environment for Qt usage... C:\WINDOWS\system32>qmake -v QMake version 2.01a Using Qt version 4.7.4 in C:\QtSDK\Desktop\Qt\4.7.4\mingw\lib BTW... I reinstalled in a different location as you can see, but with the same results

Comment: from the error message,it was 4.8.1.  Is there an directory named C:\QtSDK\Desktop\Qt\4.8.1 ?  If so, give a try to C:\QtSDK\Desktop\Qt\4.8.1\qt\qmake -v.

Comment: another solution is to install qt sdk ,you can find it in http://qt-project.org/downloads ,then select windows- Offline installer

Comment: Hi I finally came up with a sollution, I ran the qmake command from a bat file, and I removed it from the build options in Qt Creator. I know it is strange but somehow it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Running the qmake command from the command line via a bat file works.